# Selecting multiple filter options at once in django admin (suit)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-suit

In django admin , covered with django suit, you can get a drop down of the filters that you have listed in your admin.py file. Currently I can only select one option at a time within a drop down list. Is there a way to select multiple options at a time within one drop down list filter?

Comment: you mean, at the same time, rather than let the page reload, then select your next filter?

Comment: yes at the same time

Comment: you would have to override the admin template (or maybe able to just override the filter template) to display different and submit the correct get  variables.